Reducing code execution time and reducing the amount of memory for execution
What can be done to reduce code execution time? Briefly what the code does:
s - the number of lists to check, k - the number of digits that need to be removed from the lists, n - the number of numbers in the list, mobs_list - the list itself
The code is supposed to remove k numbers so that when mobs_list is divided into two parts (p1/p2), the left side is maximally larger than the right...
s = int(input())
answer = []
for _ in range(s):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    mobs_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
    
    if k == 0:
        answer.append(sum(mobs_list[:n//2:]) - sum(mobs_list[n//2::]))
    else:
        while k != 0:
            n = len(mobs_list)
            if k % 2 == 0: #скрипт для чётных
                keys = [str(key) for key in range(1,6)]
                
                var = dict.fromkeys(keys)
                
                ans = []
                

                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.pop(-1)
                p1.pop(-1)
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p2.pop(0)
                var["1"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                
 
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.pop(-1)
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                var["2"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                

                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p2.pop(0)
                var["3"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))          
                

                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                p2.append(p1[-1])
                p1.pop(-1)
                var["4"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                

                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                var["5"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))

                
                ind = str(ans.index(max(ans))+1)
                mobs_list = var[ind][0]+var[ind][1]

                k -= 2
                n -= 2
                
                if k == 0: answer.append(sum(mobs_list[:n//2:]) - sum(mobs_list[n//2::]))
                
            else: #скрипт для нечётных
                keys = [str(key) for key in range(1,5)]
                
                var = dict.fromkeys(keys)
                
                ans = []


                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.pop(-1)
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p2.pop(0)
                var["1"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))


                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p2.pop(0)
                var["2"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))


                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p1.remove(min(p1))
                p1.append(p2[0])
                p2.pop(0)
                var["3"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))
                
             
                p1, p2 = mobs_list[:n//2:], mobs_list[n//2::]
                p2.remove(max(p2))
                var["4"] = [p1,p2]
                ans.append(sum(p1)-sum(p2))

                
                ind = str(ans.index(max(ans))+1)
                mobs_list = var[ind][0]+var[ind][1]

                k -= 1
                n -= 1
                
                if k == 0: answer.append(sum(mobs_list[:n//2:]) - sum(mobs_list[n//2::]))

for item in answer: print(item)


can u provide us some example input and outputs ?

Sample input and expected output is required to understand what's needed here. Also, arbitrary input values can lead to IndexError exceptions. You need to sanity-check the inputs

@MuhammedSamedÖzmen
3
6 2
3 2 4 1 5 10
4 0
1 5 2 2
3 1
1 2 3
ans:
1
2
-1

@Arton Be specific. What are the values for s, n, k and mobs_list

@SIGHUP
s = 3
n = 6
k = 2
mob_list=[3,2,4,1,5,10]
ans=1

replace append() with list comprehension. . .
